# SageMaker Model Package Group cannot be deleted because it still contains Model Packages

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a Model Package Group in SageMaker to store different versions in the Model Registry.

```
import boto3

model_package = 'risk-model'
sagemaker_boto_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

sagemaker_boto_client.list_model_packages(ModelPackageGroupName=model_package)["ModelPackageSummaryList"]
>>> [
 {'ModelPackageGroupName': 'risk-model',
  'ModelPackageVersion': 3,
  'ModelPackageArn': 'some_arn_3',
  'ModelPackageDescription': 'New Model Version 3',
  'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 5, 15, 9, 3, 800000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
  'ModelPackageStatus': 'Completed',
  'ModelApprovalStatus': 'PendingManualApproval'},
 {'ModelPackageGroupName': 'risk-model',
  'ModelPackageVersion': 2,
  'ModelPackageArn': 'some_arn_2',
  'ModelPackageDescription': 'New Model Version 2',
  'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 5, 14, 48, 5, 150000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
  'ModelPackageStatus': 'Completed',
  'ModelApprovalStatus': 'PendingManualApproval'},
 {'ModelPackageGroupName': 'risk-model',
  'ModelPackageVersion': 1,
  'ModelPackageArn': 'some_arn_1',
  'ModelPackageDescription': 'New Model Version 1',
  'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 4, 23, 10, 38, 516000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
  'ModelPackageStatus': 'Completed',
  'ModelApprovalStatus': 'Approved'}]
```

When I want to delete the Model Package Group

```
sagemaker_boto_client.delete_model_package_group(
    ModelPackageGroupName='risk-model'
)
```

I got the following error

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteModelPackageGroup operation: Model Package Group cannot be deleted because it still contains Model Packages.
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You need to delete the model packages before you can delete the group

Answer (score 2):

You would need to first delete all the Model Packages in the Model Package Group.
Please see the [`delete_model_package()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.delete_model_package) boto3 API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marc K can you provide a complete code example with boto3?

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Marc K suggestion the following code snippet works to empty and delete a `ModelPackageGroup` using boto3

```
import boto3
import time

sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
model_package = 'risk-fraud-model'

empty_and_delete_model_package(sagemaker_client, model_package)

def empty_and_delete_model_package(sagemaker_client, mpg_name):
    mpg = sagemaker_client.list_model_packages(
        ModelPackageGroupName=mpg_name,
    )
    
    # Delete model packages if Group not empty
    model_packages = mpg.get('ModelPackageSummaryList')
    if model_packages:
        for mp in model_packages:
            sagemaker_client.delete_model_package(
                ModelPackageName=mp['ModelPackageArn']
            )
            time.sleep(1)

    # Delete model package group
    sagemaker_client.delete_model_package_group(
        ModelPackageGroupName=mpg_name
    )
```